# Angular form component does't append result to list component's array

Tags: angular

There are two separate components `users` and `user-form`.

### The goal

The goal is to use the `user-form` to post the `user`, meaning adding it to the database and then showing it in `users` html.

### The question

Why doesn't `addUser(user: User)` add the new user to the already existing `users` array? When I `console.log(this.users)` from the `users` component nothing is changed.

### ExpressJS users/post

This basically makes a new entry for a user and then uses a another query to find the user it just made (so it can get it's id number).

```
router.post('/post', (req, res) => {
    var name = req.body.name;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

    var query = `INSERT INTO ${table} VALUES (null, "${name}", "${email}", "${password}")`;
    console.log(query);

    conn.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        query = `SELECT * FROM ${table} WHERE name LIKE '%${name}%' AND email LIKE '${email}'`;
        conn.query(query, (err, result, fields) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.send(result[result.length - 1]);
        });
    });
});
```

### user-form component html

This form collects the user's input and submits it using `onSubmit()`.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #userForm="ngForm" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
               [(ngModel)]="user.name" name="name"
               required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email"
               [(ngModel)]="user.email" name="email"
               required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd"
               [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="password"
               required>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success" [disabled]="!userForm.form.valid">Submit</button>

</form>
```

### user-form component

```
    import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {User} from "../user";
import {UserService} from "../user.service";
import {UsersComponent} from "../users/users.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-user-form',
    templateUrl: './user-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./user-form.component.css'],
    providers: [UsersComponent]
})
export class UserFormComponent implements OnInit {

    user = new User(null, "Ra", "jim@gmail.com", "jimPass");
    submitted = false;

    constructor(private userService: UserService, private usersComponent: UsersComponent) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    get diagnostic() {
        return JSON.stringify(this.user);
    }

    onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;
        this.addUser(this.user);
        console.log("UserFormComponent.onSubmit(): ", this.user);
    }

    clear() {
        this.user = new User(null, "", "", "");
    }

    addUser(user: User): void {
        this.userService.postUserObject(user)
            .subscribe(
                res => {
                    console.log("addUser() next: ", res);
                    this.usersComponent.appendUser(res);
                },
                err => console.error("addUser() error: ", err),
                () => {
                    console.log("addUser() loaded: ", user);

                }
            );
        this.usersComponent.check("Some msg");
    }
}
```

### users component

```
    import {Component, Input, NgZone, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import {User} from "../user";
import {UserService} from "../user.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-users',
    templateUrl: './users.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./users.component.css'],
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
    users: User[];

    constructor(private zone: NgZone, private userService: UserService) {
        this.users = [];
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getUsers();
        //let timer = Observable.timer(2000, 5000);
        //timer.subscribe(() => this.getUsers());
    }

    getUsers(): void {
        this.userService.getUsers()
            .subscribe(
                users => {
                    this.zone.run(() => this.users = users)
                },
                error => console.error(error),
                () => console.log("Users: ", this.users)
            );
    }

    appendUser(user: User): void {
        console.log("UsersComponent.appendUser(): ", user);
        this.zone.run(() => this.users.push(user));
    }

    logUsers(): void {
        console.log("logUsers(): ", this.users);
    }

    check(msg: string): void {
        console.log("check(): ", msg);
    }
}
```

### users html

```
    <ul *ngIf="users.length > 0" class="users">
    <li *ngFor="let user of users">
        {{user.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

## [Angular app github link](https://github.com/AquaSolid/MEAN-stack-diversity)

## [ExpressJS app github link](https://github.com/AquaSolid/MEAN-stack-diversity-express)

Comment: You really have not asked any question here

Comment: @Sajeetharan I edited my post

Comment: why do you have zones running everywhere?

Comment: Because I implemented a time-based function which queries the database and manually refreshes the HTML view. Knowing that this is poor, I decided to rethink, but I left those out by mistake

Comment: If you want to manually refresh the view, you should think about using immutables, and OnPush change detection strategy. You should be able to accomplish refreshes without the need for NgZone.

Comment: @pixelbits Well, that's why I'm trying, but the issue is that `users.push()` doesn't actually modify the `users` array therefore there is no change to detect.

Comment: Can we see your route for the users module?

Comment: @Jed I added github links to the project at the bottom of the post. Feel free to see anything

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the console.log after adding to the array and you do not have to explicitly mention this.zone.run(), try,

```
appendUser(user: User): void {
    this.users.push(user);
    console.log("UsersComponent.appendUser(): ", this.users);
}
```

also place console.log inside subscribe

```
this.userService.getUsers()
            .subscribe(
                users => {
                   this.users = users;
                   console.log("Users: ", this.users)
                },
                error => console.error(error) 
            );
```

Comment: This didn't change a thing and my question is why even it would?

Answer (score 0):

I think if they are on separate page and separate route, you should just redirect to users component after the add is successful. No need to use NgZone and no need to inject the users component.